# Behavior of :active in Firefox's Responsive Design Mode

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design, pseudo-class

Firefox offers Responsive Design Mode, allowing you to view web pages as if they were rendered on a smaller screen, like a mobile phone.

I'm making a web app and want to apply styles to a button that is currently being tapped by a finger, so the user knows they're pressing the button.

I'm developing on a desktop computer though (Windows) and using Firefox's Responsive Design Mode, and when I use the mouse to click a button, the `:active` pseudo-class is not applied so I'm not sure how to test out my styles.

Is this expected, and is there something I should be using instead?

---

I'm using React, so a workaround I tried is to use a state var `isActive` and use events `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp` to maintain it, as such:

```
const onMouseDown = () => this.setState({ isActive: true });
const onMouseUp = () => this.setState({ isActive: false });
```

That also doesn't work correctly, only in Responsive Design Mode. Interestingly, though, right-click does apply my styles, but left-click does not (and that's the important one).